# auto dependencies not working with eclipse CDT C++ project

Tags: g++, eclipse-cdt

It seems the generated auto dependency rules in Eclipse CDT 8.1.0 are incorrect.  To illustrate the problem I made an empty Executable project and added two files.

**test.cpp**:

```
    #include "SomeOtherHeader.h"
    int main(void){return 0;}
```

and
**SomeOtherHeader.h** (which is empty)

Compiling this project causes Eclipse to generate the "Debug" folder in the project directory with the subdir.mk makefile include.

Contents of **Debug/subdir.mk**:

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 
CPP_SRCS += \
../test.cpp 

OBJS += \
./test.o 

CPP_DEPS += \
./test.d 


# Each subdirectory must supply rules for building sources it contributes
%.o: ../%.cpp
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler'
    g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '
```

Its the `-MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)"` line that concerns me because the MT option creates a nonsensical dependency in the file Debug/test.d

```
test.d: ../test.cpp ../SomeOtherHeader.h

../SomeOtherHeader.h:
```

Changing `-MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)"` to `-MT"$@"` in Debug/subdir.mk yields a more reasonable Debug/test.d:

```
test.o: ../test.cpp ../SomeOtherHeader.h

../SomeOtherHeader.h:
```

It looks like the "-MT" string is hard coded in the managedbuilder.core java code:

```
$ unzip -p /usr/lib64/eclipse/dropins/cdt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core_8.1.0.201206111645.jar | strings | grep '\-MT'
-MT"
-MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)"
-MT"
-MT"$@"
-MT"$(@:%.d=%.o)"
```

It looks like the winning option `-MT"$@"` is in there, but how do I instruct the managedbuilder to use it?  Does `-MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)"` serve any practical purpose?

Its my first time posting on this site so be easy on me :)

Comment: I just started using CDT and noticed the same nonsense. I checked the source code, the responsible file is here: https://github.com/eclipse/cdt/blob/master/build/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core/src/org/eclipse/cdt/managedbuilder/makegen/gnu/DefaultGCCDependencyCalculator2Commands.java. The line that generates "-MT\"$(@:%.o=%.d)\"" is there since 2006. Why nobody else complained and why it is not fixed yet?

Comment: I've just raised https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=468417 and submitted the pull request https://github.com/eclipse/cdt/pull/1 for the proposed change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-MT"$@"` to compiler flags in `Project Properties->C/C++ Buid->Settings->GCC Compiler->Miscellaneous->Other flags`. Eclipse will simply add this flag to compilation line inside makefile. Output inside `test.d` file should be something like:

```
test.o test.d: ../test.cpp ../SomeOtherHeader.h

../SomeOtherHeader.h:
```

Comment: @rmccabe3701: If my reply was helpful please mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: This definitely is useful but it deserves a proper fix at the Eclipse front I believe. People shouldn't be banging their heads and look for a work around for such a simple to fix issue which has been long standing, well, for almost 10 years.